# Configuring NHibernate to work with Spring.NET AOP Proxy objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, aop, spring.net

I'm using Spring.NET AOP to determine when a C# persistent object has change any of its properties (per Spring.AopQuickStart.Step6.2010 in Spring.NET/examples), but I'm getting a MappingException - No persister for: DecoratorAopProxy_8aa4d47e877a48b4828bf7a6a51bbedf

Here's my code:

```
var person = Repository.GetById(personId);
var personProxy = GetProxy(person);
// udpate some properties in personProxy - this is where my advisor determines if/what has changed
Repository.Save(personProxy); // exception thrown here
```

Here's what GetProxy looks like (per the AopQuickStart example):

```
private static Person GetProxy(Person target)
{
    var proxyFactory = new Spring.AOP.Framework.ProxyFactory(target);
    proxyFactory.AddAdvisor(new ModificationAdvisor(target.GetType()));
    proxyFactory.AddIntroduction(new IsModifiedAdvisor());
    proxyFactory.ProxyTargetType = true;

    return (Person)proxyFactory.GetProxy();
}
```

I think the issue is that the GetType for the object passed to NHibernate's session Save is "DecoratorAopProxy", and not Person which throws NHibernate off.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the implementation of DataBindingIntercepter.cs and DataBindingFactory.cs

https://github.com/ayende/Effectus/tree/master/Effectus/Infrastructure

Comment: Perfect! Just for future reference the key is to (a) create a custom interceptor by subclassing NHibernate.EmptyInterceptor (or implement IInterceptor), (b) override its GetEntityName() to return the appropriate type instead of the proxy and (c) set your custom interceptor when creating NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.